# Simple javascript removing geojson from leaflet map cannot be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I've been through a number of solutions in stack overflow and leaflet documentation itself  saying that to clear layers I could either use the following:

1,) `map.removeLayer(geojsonFeature);`

2.) `map.clearLayers()`

3.) `L.GeoJson().clearLayers()`

Quite a simple question, but probably the way I handle it could be the reason, so I'll also try my best to walk you through it without a bunch of codes, hoping someone could help me determine the reason this isn't working.

1.) Main html `index.html`, gets geojson with multiple features `fullFeature`.

2.) Click button, fire ajax on success: `map.removeLayer(fullFeature)` and animate in a div content with ajax url `next.html` html page.

3.) Server side: a single feature (from `fullFeature`) is rendered and passed as geojson format. This is added to map like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var single_feature = {{ single_feature | safe}};
    var single_feature = L.geoJSON(single_feature);

    single_feature.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(single_feature.getBounds());

    $(".return").click(function(){
        //map.removeLayer(sinlge_feature);
        L.geoJSON().clearLayers();
        $(".feature_display").animate({right: '-400px'});
    });
});
```

4.) Hence me, trying to click `$(".return")` would not execute `.clearLayers();` but would execute the line `$(".feature_display").animate({right: '-400px'});`

Comment: Are you sure `map.removeLayer(single_feature)` does not work? (once the type for `sinlge` is corrected to `single`)

Comment: I don't really understand the 4). Do you have any error with your clearLayer ?

Comment: @Baptiste No I tried opening the js debugger it doesn't show any clearLayer error

Comment: @ghybs ah just a typo while editing this block of code, but yes. I'll check again

Answer (score 0):

It does execute `clearLayers` but you are calling `clearLayers` on `L.geoJSON()` which creates a new empty L.GeoJSON layer. That obviously does nothing. You should call `clearLayers` on the instance of `L.GeoJSON` you created before.

```
$(".return").click(function(){
    single_feature.clearLayers();
    $(".feature_display").animate({right: '-400px'});
});
```

Comment: ahhh yeah that is true. I tried editing this and it now works on that page. can I just have a little more help? On that django template page it works. But after I click a button (going to edit form) then clicking the cancel button on the edit form to go back to the page where the `.return` button is, it will not fire the `clearLayers()` Is there some association that the leaflet script is not working after the `edit` ajax page despite it being on the document ready state?

Comment: Your edit form is on the same page (act like a modal) or is on another page ?